# Trying to send a registration request to to an API in xamarin Forms

Tags: c#

Am trying to connect to an API I built with the client version, running the client app with break points I can see that the data I pass in(signing up) gets passed down but when it get to the the PostAsync method that sends the data to the api the application breaks and I get 'system-net-webexception-failed-to-connect-to-localhost-127-0-0-1-44391' and an accompanying error that reads 'The selected debug engine does not support any code executing on the current thread (e.g. only native runtime code is executing)', there's no red highlight to indicate where the error is which makes this a real head scratcher for me.....
Some insight on the issue will be greatly appreciated.

```
Sub.Clicked += async (object sender, EventArgs e) =>
          {
              if (!Conection.IsConnected)
              {
                  await DisplayAlert("No Connection", "Please turn on or reset your data connection", "Cancle");
                  
              }

             
              var entirs = new string[] { Email.Text, Password.Text, FN.Text, LN.Text, Phone.Text};

              var jcon = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(entirs);
              var contain = new StringContent(jcon, Encoding.UTF8, "aplication/json");
              message.Timeout = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 100);
              var outcome = await message.PostAsync("https://localhost:5001/api/v1/identity/Register", contain);

              if (outcome.StatusCode==HttpStatusCode.Created)
              {
                  await DisplayAlert("Success", "Entries have been loaded", "X");
                  Application.Current.MainPage = new NavigationPage(new Selection());
              }

              else
              {
                  await DisplayAlert("Failed", outcome.StatusCode.ToString(), "cancel");
              };
          };
```

Comment: Normally we'd ask for [MRE]... but in this case you need to provide information on you local networking setup... and how/what is routing request on localhost (as clearly `https://localhost:5001` is pointed somewhere else)... I'm not sure how well this question fits SO... or where you can get better help. You definitely should [edit] post with that information (and example of Fiddler/Postman successfully call to the same url) to get help.

Comment: Hopefully I've understood what you need to be able to give me feed back....am not using postman or fidler, am using swagger for the purposes of my development, so just to clarify, you need the pipeline in my startup.cs from the api(how/what is routing request on localhost) and my local networking setup......this I must confess am a tad bit unclear.